# if two strings are in multiple lines print them only once

Tags: awk, grep

I want to print lines that have `stringOne` and `stringTwo` or `stringThree` and `stringFour` but only once. For example there is a file with the following contents:

```
This is the first stringOne line and here is stringTwo
There is another line stringOne and also stringTwo is here
Here is stringThree and stringFour
some other lines which only contain stringOne
some more lines which only contain stringTwo
ThisLineHas/stringOne/and/ofcourse/stringTwo
Lets have another stringThree and stringFour
Lines which dont have any of specified strings
```

As you see in the above we have a pair of strings on line 1,2,3,6 and 7.

**This is the desired output:**

```
This is the first stringOne line and here is stringTwo
Here is stringThree and stringFour
```

I tried `grep -Fxq "$stringOne.*$stringTwo\|$stringTwo.*$stringOne" myfile.txt` in for loops but it doesn't give me the result I want.

Comment: `stringOne and stringTwo or stringThree and stringFour` like, almost literally `awk '(/stringOne / && /stringTwo/) || (/stringThree/ && /stringFour/)'`? `but only once` You want print the line once, or you want to print _the first line_ that matches? Is each pair separately, so first line that matches the first pair?

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to print the first line that matches each pair. If there are multiple lines contain ```stringOne and stringTwo``` I want to print the first line that matches, also the same for ```stringThree and stringFour``` and so on and so forth

Comment: On your input `grep -Em1 "stringOne.*stringTwo|stringTwo.*stringOne"` works better than your `grep`, but better switch to `awk`.

Comment: @WalterA Why do you recommend  ```awk``` over ```grep```? Is your recommendation only for this issue or in total? I'm not familiar with ```awk``` well, can you recommend me some sources to learn it better?

Comment: @sof3 For simple tasks you do not need `awk`. When you can use `grep` or `sed` without difficult constructions, those are fine. When you want to remember some state from a previous line when parsing the next, you will need fancy constructions, subprocesses or other (funny ;-) complicated stuff that `awk` would solve in a few simple lines. When you want for substrings all appear in one line in any order, the `awk` solution is still very simple. When you only want to find lines with "something", use `grep`.
I have no sources to recommand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this `gnu-awk` solution:

```sh
awk -v wp1='\\ystringOne\\y.+\\ystringTwo\\y' -v wp2='\\ystringThree\\y.+\\ystringFour\\y' '($0 ~ wp1 && !matched[wp1]++) || ($0 ~ wp2 && !matched[wp2]++)' file

This is the first stringOne line and here is stringTwo
Here is stringThree and stringFour
```

- `wp1` and `wp2` are for word pairs one and two regex.
- `\\y` is used as for word boundary.
- `matched` is an associative array to allow given regex to be matched only once.

Comment: it works but what if there are multiple strings to match? consider I have a file with thousands lines. How can I do the job?

Comment: No matter how many lines are there in the file, this approach will still work fine.

Comment: should I replace ```$first``` and ```$second``` with ```stringOne and stringTwo```? for example writing a for loop like: ```for first in $(< first_file.txt); do for second in $(<second_file.txt); do awk -v wp1='\\y$first\\y.+\\y$second\\y' '($0 ~ wp1 && !matched[wp1]++)'; done done.  is it correct?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand purpose of `first_file.txt` and `second_file.txt` here. May be you can clarify that by editing your question and showing better samples.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your solution. It now works.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to print lines that have stringOne and stringTwo or stringThree and stringFour but only once

If you want to print the first matched line, you have to keep "state" (did I print the line or not yet?). You could:

```
awk '
  /stringOne /  && /stringTwo/  && !firstpair++
  /stringThree/ && /stringFour/ && !secondpair++
'
```

Comment: you can improve with `/stringOne/ && /stringTwo/ && !f++` etc.

Comment: Improve as in use awk tricks to shorten the code? Och, sure, that's the awk way.

Comment: @KamilCuk Your solution works too but I voted for anubhava answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @karakfa What if the string contains ```//``` for example one the strings is ```https://example.com/```. In this case I get a ```syntax error``` which is related to ```//```

Comment: Since the strings are not variables, you can escape the special chars when you're writing the pattern.

Comment: @karakfa But it is reading strings from a for loop so it is like ```$something```. Is there any way to escape chars if they are variables? ```for something in $(< myfile.txt)```

Comment: For that you cannot use this construct.  You should introduce it as a variable and check for string equality instead of regex match.  For that you don't need to escape special chars.

Comment: @sof31 `for something in $(< myfile.txt)` Kindly read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . Also, [here is a awk introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) where you can learn how to "introduce it as a variable and check for string equality instead of regex match".